# access to a rails controller variable from js file

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails-3, will-paginate

I have a index.htm.erb file that has a render template file in it.

```
<div id="product"> <%= render :template => "shop/products" %> </div>
```

in its controller I have

```
  def index
    @products = Product.paginate :page => params[:page], :per_page => 6 
  end
```

I have a js file that is at the bottom of my index.html file which has a script in it to get will_paginate url.

```
$(window).scroll(function(){
        if( $(this).scrollTop() > ( ( $(document).height() - $(this).height() ) - 50 ) ){
            var link = $('.pagination .next_page').attr('href');
            $.getScript( link );
        }


        });
```

This getScript call to a js file that is of the same name as the index.html.erb. so its index.js.erb.
Inside the js.erb file I have a

```
console.log("products = ", @products);
```

I get an error trying to retrieve the instance variable. 500 Internal Server Error
I don't have access to the @products variable. 
What do I need to do to have access to this variable.

UPDATED:

I'm using the same tutorial from http://railscasts.com/episodes/114-endless-page-revised?autoplay=true
the only difference is I'm using a template inside my index.html.erb
So I still don't understand how in the tutorial they have access to the instance variable but I don't

Answer (score 1):

**DISREGARD ANSWER**

I am not a big RoR guy so I might be missunderstanding this situation a bit, but I still want to try to help you out. Here is my guess:

This is not really RoR related but more a backend to frontend question in general. JavaScript runs entirely in the browser while Rails only runs on the server. Therefore JS has no idea of all the variables you define within the Ruby environmt. If you want a variable to be accessible in JS you have to somehow write it into the page.

Simply put as an example you need to do something along this:

```
<script>
    var productName = "<%= @product.name %>";
</script>
```

So Rails will parse the html and replace the `<%= @product.name %>` part with the actual name. So the browser retrieves an html that lookes something like this

```
<script>
    var productName = "Ice Cream";
</script>
```

This is one very simple that way you can pass variables from the backend to the frontend.

Comment: Thanks Mathias but I'm using the tutorial from railscast and they are able to access the instance variable. The only difference is I'm using a template. See my updated comments in my original post.

Comment: Yes, Mathias your answer is incorrect because rails has the ability to build the JS dynamically using ruby before it is served to the client. Things have changed in >rails 3.1 but in 3.0 this is still possible

Answer (score 1):

Try passing the `@products` variable to your template explicitly:

`<%= render :template => "shop/products", :locals => {:my_products => @products} %>`

You would then use the variable `my_products` in your `shop/products` template wherever you're currently using `@products`.